# Should a table be made for associations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, rails-migrations

I am new to rails and have a very basic question.

While creating models, for ex. I have to store recipe and its steps. Now should i make recipe table, steps table and recipe_steps table or should i have recipe , steps table and in the model for recipe define has_many :steps?

Any help would be great.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You always need to have 3 tables in your database. As you said `recipes` `steps` and `recipe_steps`

Then you have two solutions with your models. The first one with 3 models:

```
class Recipe
  has_many :recipe_steps
  has_many :steps, through: :recipe_steps
end

class Step
  has_many :recipe_steps
  has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_steps
end

class RecipeStep
  belongs_to :step
  belongs_to :recipe
end
```

The second one with only two models:

```
class Recipe
  has_and_belongs_to_many :steps
end

class Step
  has_and_belongs_to_many :recipes
end
```

You will use the second solution if you don't want to manage data in the `recipe_steps` table. But if you want to add some informations in this table (price or quantity for example), you must use the first solution.

In all cases you must create the 3 tables.

You will find more information here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

I hope this help

Comment: Thanks Cupra: That was helpful. Though i think i need to clarify, each recipe has multiple steps, basically a one to many relation. In this case too, do we need 3 tables?

Comment: For one to many relation you don't need 3 tables. You will have 2 tables with a `belongs_to` for the model which have one relation and `has_many` for the other model. You will find more informations here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Yup thanks Cupra. Appreciate the help. I am doing exactly as you suggested, wanted to be sure of what i am doing. Thanks again.